# is there any online facility for backing linux data via ftp

Tags: linux, backup, ftp, online-backup

I have around 50GB of data on my VPS . Is there any online website service which can provide me some 100GB space and ftp service so that i can upload my backups there with rsync .

I don't want to on home computer but online

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you're a student or researcher there's no free service for this that I'm aware of.

There's always EvBackup

http://www.evbackup.com/?gclid=CMT8wI200agCFUMUKgodi3eRiw

Answer (score 3):

I've never used them, but it sounds like [rsync.net](http://www.rsync.net) could serve your needs (not free, but very reasonable).

Comment: Its very very costly , Evbackup is way cheaper . ihave 100GB of data

Comment: @Moorage - 80c/gb is actually fairly reasonable. EVBackup is cheaper, but I wouldn't say "way" cheaper.

Answer (score 0):

You can try tarring and then mailing your backups to a gmail account. Which provides quite a bit of storage. You could also try using [Dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/)